# Firebase cloud function onCreate not running?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kRgVxULbag&t=1108s) and I'm trying to get .onCreate to work, but nothing's happening.

The code I'm trying to replicate is at around 19:30 in the video, and here's what I've got:

```
exports.createinvite = functions.firestore
    .document('referrals/{referralid}')
    .onCreate(event => {
    console.log('asfasdfasdf')

    const docid = event.params.referralid;
    const code = event.data.data().thing;
    const referralref = admin.filestore().collection('referrals').doc(docid)

    return referralref.update({message: `asfasfasdfa`})
});
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How are you triggering the function? Also: is your function getting invoked (you can see this in the logging output), or not even that?

Comment: For now I’m just manually adding documents to the collection. And sorry, what do you mean by logging output? I’m new to all of this haha

Comment: The [Cloud Functions Logs panel in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/functions/logs?severity=DEBUG) shows the invocations and output of recent Cloud Functions.

Comment: It says the function is being run, and the error is: TypeError: Cannot read property ‘referralid’ of undefined at exports.createinvite.functions.firestore.document.onCreate.event

Answer (score 0):

You are following a very old tutorial, and I suggest you stop following it and learn from something newer, such as the [official Firebase videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM).  The APIs have changed.

Please also follow the [documentation for Firestore triggers](http://826-051) to learn what an onCreate function looks like today.  They take two parameters, a snapshot and a context:

```
exports.createinvite = functions.firestore
    .document('referrals/{referralid}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => { ... })
```

The wildcards from the pattern are available in `context.params`.  You will use `context.params.referralid` to get the value of the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [Firestore event triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#event_triggers), you'll see that `onCreate` is called with two parameters: `snapshot` and `context`. The `params` property exists on the `context`/second parameter, and not on the first.

So:

```
exports.createinvite = functions.firestore
    .document('referrals/{referralid}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('asfasdfasdf')

    const docid = context.params.referralid;
    const code = snapshot.data().thing;
    ...
```

I highly recommend checking out the documentation if something from a tutorial doesn't work, as the product may have been updated since the tutorial was created.

Comment: True. I always follow the documentation. It's one of the most well documented set of products.